# Have app return JSON when called Ruby, Rspec error?

Tags: json, ruby, module, rspec

I have an app that is fully written, it parses some JSON, reorganizes it and then is supposed to return JSON when called. My rspec test is written as follows

```
final_json = RestaurantApp.call(json)
JSON.load(final_json)
```

My call method within the app ends with the final data as an array of hashes which are finalized like this.

```
final_data = [described_array_of_hashes]
final_data.to_json
```

As far as I can tell it works, when I print the array of hashes it's in a perfect JSON structure so the return should be correct, but rspec keeps pulling the same error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant RestaurantApp::JSON
```

I've never encountered a class module with ::JSON at the end, can someone explain why this is being raised by rspec?

Thanks in advance, my apologies for any confusion, I'm still a very fresh programmer

Comment: Have you tried adding `require 'json'`. It might be that `JSON` is not defined and its being searched in current namespace, which might be `RestaurantApp` in this case.

Comment: *facepalm* That was it. I totally forgot to add my requirement at the top.

Thanks for the help!